# Binding value in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a XML value in controller and i'm passing that value to jsp page and binding as shown in the below code.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value='${xml}'/>
```

It is binding the value as shown in the below.

```
 <input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value='
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Esign AuthMode="1" aspId="ASPRBLBMUMTEST043" ekycId="448988431774" ekycIdType="A" ekycMode="U" organizationFlag="N" preVerified="n" responseSigType="pkcs7" responseUrl="http://10.80.49.41" sc="Y" ts="2018-01-19T11:42:55" txn="UKC:eSign:6539:20180119114250963" ver="2.0">
        <Docs>
            <InputHash docInfo="Signing pdf" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" id="1">30e3ed7f512da50206b8720d52457309c87f4edfee85d08f937aef3f955fb7af</InputHash>
        </Docs>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>kQEB9r4dd5hhdaPxc4sjPMG3SGM=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>MSgEXK2+GpwnRBr3vLNncqc9FOY0oDhjlhfyihOjrUPFZAL8eBms6jXdhoWGlrypaF6hE70ZltDQbQTArrk/mfCmoVvna7yEJN9gDh6gAHbh9Zj4BEBdWhd85DKbAdtSy8zYTKIeIjhFBzOItUAhSN7lFrEFVrTLV5wO38hswD7LlaY4ZBSNMWbpHPx+Io6ukdP8b4n95dqoB9iiqKxg3nK0RslhLRcPoe4B2AsdoiZ42iY/tZ4disOzyOCyCdE8nRxipJbP9HZS3psCSCar3CPSigXiNk6fY7+bDEFbJrfoqhHBk1hasx2m0TbxZVeOIPSUPRYpekHCm0sm4RvZhA==</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <X509Data>
                    <X509SubjectName>CN=AAA Bank Test,OU=AAA Bank IT Dept,O=AAA Bank,L=Delhi,ST=Delhi,C=91</X509SubjectName>
                    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
                </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </Esign>'/>
```

But i want to bind like below without spaces.

```
<input type="hidden" id="thisField" name="inputName" value='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Esign AuthMode="1" aspId="ASPRBLBMUMTEST043" ekycId="448988431774" ekycIdType="A" ekycMode="U" organizationFlag="N" preVerified="n" responseSigType="pkcs7" responseUrl="http://10.80.49.41" sc="Y" ts="2018-01-19T11:42:55" txn="UKC:eSign:6539:20180119114250963" ver="2.0"><Docs><InputHash docInfo="Signing pdf" hashAlgorithm="SHA256" id="1">30e3ed7f512da50206b8720d52457309c87f4edfee85d08f937aef3f955fb7af</InputHash></Docs><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><Reference URI=""><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>kQEB9r4dd5hhdaPxc4sjPMG3SGM=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>MSgEXK2+GpwnRBr3vLNncqc9FOY0oDhjlhfyihOjrUPFZAL8eBms6jXdhoWGlrypaF6hE70ZltDQbQTArrk/mfCmoVvna7yEJN9gDh6gAHbh9Zj4BEBdWhd85DKbAdtSy8zYTKIeIjhFBzOItUAhSN7lFrEFVrTLV5wO38hswD7LlaY4ZBSNMWbpHPx+Io6ukdP8b4n95dqoB9iiqKxg3nK0RslhLRcPoe4B2AsdoiZ42iY/tZ4disOzyOCyCdE8nRxipJbP9HZS3psCSCar3CPSigXiNk6fY7+bDEFbJrfoqhHBk1hasx2m0TbxZVeOIPSUPRYpekHCm0sm4RvZhA==</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><X509Data><X509SubjectName>CN=Rbl Bank Test,OU=AAA Bank IT Dept,O=AAA Bank,L=Delhi,ST=Delhi,C=91</X509SubjectName><X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate></X509Data></KeyInfo></Signature></Esign>'/>
```

> Is there any way to bind like as shown in the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a manipulation of the xml string in your controller with a little regex to eliminate the newlines and whitespace.

Here is a little java app to show the regex in work against your xml string.

```
public class StripXmlWhitespace {

       public static void main (String [] args) {
           String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" + 
                "    <Esign AuthMode=\"1\" aspId=\"ASPRBLBMUMTEST043\" ekycId=\"448988431774\" ekycIdType=\"A\" ekycMode=\"U\" organizationFlag=\"N\" preVerified=\"n\" responseSigType=\"pkcs7\" responseUrl=\"http://10.80.49.41\" sc=\"Y\" ts=\"2018-01-19T11:42:55\" txn=\"UKC:eSign:6539:20180119114250963\" ver=\"2.0\">\n" + 
                "        <Docs>\n" + 
                "            <InputHash docInfo=\"Signing pdf\" hashAlgorithm=\"SHA256\" id=\"1\">30e3ed7f512da50206b8720d52457309c87f4edfee85d08f937aef3f955fb7af</InputHash>\n" + 
                "        </Docs>\n" + 
                "        <Signature xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#\">\n" + 
                "            <SignedInfo>\n" + 
                "                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315\"/>\n" + 
                "                <SignatureMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1\"/>\n" + 
                "                <Reference URI=\"\">\n" + 
                "                    <Transforms>\n" + 
                "                        <Transform Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature\"/>\n" + 
                "                    </Transforms>\n" + 
                "                    <DigestMethod Algorithm=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1\"/>\n" + 
                "                    <DigestValue>kQEB9r4dd5hhdaPxc4sjPMG3SGM=</DigestValue>\n" + 
                "                </Reference>\n" + 
                "            </SignedInfo>\n" + 
                "            <SignatureValue>MSgEXK2+GpwnRBr3vLNncqc9FOY0oDhjlhfyihOjrUPFZAL8eBms6jXdhoWGlrypaF6hE70ZltDQbQTArrk/mfCmoVvna7yEJN9gDh6gAHbh9Zj4BEBdWhd85DKbAdtSy8zYTKIeIjhFBzOItUAhSN7lFrEFVrTLV5wO38hswD7LlaY4ZBSNMWbpHPx+Io6ukdP8b4n95dqoB9iiqKxg3nK0RslhLRcPoe4B2AsdoiZ42iY/tZ4disOzyOCyCdE8nRxipJbP9HZS3psCSCar3CPSigXiNk6fY7+bDEFbJrfoqhHBk1hasx2m0TbxZVeOIPSUPRYpekHCm0sm4RvZhA==</SignatureValue>\n" + 
                "            <KeyInfo>\n" + 
                "                <X509Data>\n" + 
                "                    <X509SubjectName>CN=AAA Bank Test,OU=AAA Bank IT Dept,O=AAA Bank,L=Delhi,ST=Delhi,C=91</X509SubjectName>\n" + 
                "                    <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>\n" + 
                "                </X509Data>\n" + 
                "            </KeyInfo>\n" + 
                "        </Signature>\n" + 
                "    </Esign>";
           String output = xmlString.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><");
           System.out.println(xmlString);
           System.out.println(output);

       }

}
```

All you need in your controller is the regex.

```
xml = xmlString.replaceAll(">\\s+<", "><");
```

Essentially unformat the xml before you send it bind it to the view.  I hope that helps.

Comment: In the controller xml value is proper means there is no spaces,while binding after jsp page only i'm getting the whitespaces. Is there any way to manipulate the xml in jsp?

Comment: Yes you can manipulate the xml in the jsp.  You can write a custom JSP tag which will perform the regex replacement in the JSP page.  I would certainly use the 2.0 specification of custom tags as they are much easier to implement.  If you want I can help provide details.  Note: even when you pull this off you are going to run into issues with placing all this xml into a input field; part will bleed into the page because of double quotes around the value and quotes within your xml.  Do you want to escape the XML as well?  What are you ultimately trying to do?